# Javascript: How to calculate the exact position of the viewport?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

My problem is I need to get the position of the viewport relative to the extent of the entire document.  I am only concerned with Firefox.

My issue is that everything I have read says that:

```
viewport height is window.innerHeight
scroll position is window.pageYOffset
document total height is document.height
```

So, I would expect that if I scrolled to the bottom of a page that

```
window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset == document.height
```

But it doesn't! Can someone please explain to me why this is?

Comment: Some further investigation has shown me that in *some* cases this does work. It seems to break when the body height is explicitly set to 100%; this is the case for pages on Wikipedia. 

In these cases, all methods I have checked for the total document height returns the viewport height only. Firefox must set the values to be 100% of the viewport. Any clever tricks to access the actual height of the document in all cases would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but you can get the amount scrolled of the page in Firefox with `document.documentElement.scrollTop`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When scrolling all the way to the bottom, this thould return true

```
window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset == document.documentElement.scrollHeight
```

Document.height can be misleading because it is sometimes set to 100% in the CSS, which messes it up.